# Passing private variable to base class constructor

Tags: c#

I want to pass a value to the base class constructor. The problem which I am facing is that the value is stored in a private variable inside derived class. Is it possible to pass it? or is it a good approach to do like this?

This is what I tried

```
class Filtering : Display
{
    private int length = 10000;
    public Filtering():base(length)
    {
    }
}
```

It is showing

> An object reference is required for non-static field, method or
>   property

Base class

```
abstract class Display
{
    public Display(int length)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Is there any other way other than making it `static`?

Comment: `length` needs it's type as well. And `Display` class needs a constructor which takes parameter with the same type as `length`.

Comment: @SonerGonul my bad ;)

Comment: Hopefully `Display` has a getter property that returns the `length`... so you shouldn't need a local copy.

Comment: Please show the constructor of the base class.

Comment: Can you instead tell us what *problem* this is meant to solve? It's a little too abstract at the moment, *and* you're just showing us your attempted solution.

Comment: @Codor base class is added.

Comment: @Bharadwaj, i'm not sure inheritance is the answer to this kind of scenario - in fact, I think we might have a X/Y situation. Can you explain the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: By the way, class names smell bad. I cannot see how a Filtering can be a Display ...

Comment: Someone posted an answer, by making it a `const` it is working! @answered_person can you re-post that answer?

Comment: @Chips_100: IMHO, the answer you posted seems quite appropriate and useful for the OP's needs, not even counting the fact that the OP themselves has specifically indicated your answer is just what they wanted. Please undelete your answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Is that approach is correct? That answer worked for me actually

Comment: I agree with the other comments that your question is vague and may not properly reflect what you really need. But, given what you've asked and taking the code you posted literally, I would have answered your question exactly as @Chips_100 did, i.e. use a named `const` to represent the value, and use it for both the field init and the base constructor call.

Comment: I also don't understand the downvote (granted, only one so far). While you _might_ benefit (i.e. get better answers) from a question that explains the real-world scenario better, and while there are other questions that discuss this specific error message, I was unable to find an actual _duplicate_ question (i.e. the others are not really the same kind of usage or problem), and your code example is quite clear, simple, and well-presented. This question could easily wind up being a useful reference for future readers who are similarly inexperienced in C#.

Comment: I've copied the useful answer to a new one under my name. For now, feel free to accept/upvote/ignore as you prefer, but please do post a comment directed at me to let me know if and when @Chips_100 undeletes his answer, and I will gladly remove mine (no need for redundant answers :) ).

Comment: @PeterDuniho There is no such real time scenario I found as such with this code. I was playing around with what all I know till now in `c#`. So accidentally I encountered this. As per question, I don't think there should be any real time scenario required to do something different right ;) and Thanks for letting me know who actually answered my quest :)

Comment: _"I don't think there should be any real time scenario required"_ -- I could not agree more with that statement. You are absolutely right. Considering the academic nature of the question, I find it useful, novel, and well-presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as answerer [Chips_100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927511/chips-100) wrote in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33516462) (currently deleted by owner):

---

If you want length to be an instance variable, but still supply it to the base constructor, I would suggest something like the following:

```
private const int DefaultLength = 10000;

private int length = DefaultLength;

public Filtering() : base(DefaultLength)
{
}
```

---

I haven't seen any indication the original author of this answer is inclined to undelete his own post. At the same time, while I would have written basically the same thing, I'd rather not take credit for an answer already present, authored by someone else. So I've converted this to a Community Wiki answer.